# Why does my command read with fgets() not work with execlp(), but the same command hard-coded works correctly?

Tags: c, linux

I have C program where i am reading user input and running that in child process. But somehow execlp is not printing anything on console. When i use execlp("ls","ls", NULL), it works fine but using user input does not print anything on console.

**The Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    char str[1024];
    printf("This program forks a Unix process and execute a command string.\n");
    printf("Enter command string:");
    fgets(str,sizeof(str),stdin);

    printf("entered string %s",str);
    int BeforeparentID=getpid();

    printf("\nParent process ID before fork():%d",BeforeparentID);

    int cid =fork();
    int AfterparentID=getpid();
    printf("\nParent process ID after fork():%d",AfterparentID);
    printf("\nChild process ID afterr fork():%d\n",cid);

    sleep(1);
    if(cid==0){
        execlp(str,str,NULL); //this does not print anything
    }
    else{
        sleep(1);
        waitpid(cid,0,0);
    }
}
```

**Sample Execution**

```
This program forks a Unix process and execute a command string.
Enter command string:ls
entered string ls

Parent process ID before fork():15368
Parent process ID after fork():15368
Child process ID afterr fork():15369
Parent process ID before fork():15368
Parent process ID after fork():15369
Child process ID afterr fork():0
```

and that's it; no directory listing. Why?

Comment: If you type `ls -al` as the command, then you'll need to break the string into two strings `str1 = "ls"` and `str2 = "-al"` and then call `execlp` with `execlp(str1, str1, str2, NULL)`. Actually you should use `execvp`. But that's a whole different question. You should accept the answer to this question by clicking the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not sending the same thing when entering `ls`. You finish that input with a newline (`'\n'`), which `fgets` *keeps* at the tail of your input string. Thusly, you're actually executing:

```
execlp("ls\n", "ls\n", NULL);
```

As you don't check the result of executing `execlp` (lots of people don't, but it would have been educational here, as it would indicate an error), you don't see the problem and simply assume it worked (a mistake I hedge a bet you'll make far less frequently now; *check your return results*).

Trim the newline off the input string:

```
char *nl = strrchr(str, '\n');
if (n1)
    *n1 = 0;
```

*then* send it to `execlp`.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks WhozCraig, it worked.I added below code:       if(str[strlen(str)-1]=='\n'){
str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
}                                                                                                                                               But it is working only for ls command. If i give ls -al on command line, it does not work.                                                                                               Thannks for help!

Comment: @user3391303 thats going to eventually be a string separation issue to solve. Best of luck with that. glad this helped.

Comment: You don't need to test the result of `execlp()` per se (see whether it is -1 or not); if the function returns, it failed, whereas if it succeeds, it doesn't return.  But you do need to print an error message and exit.  And the code using `waitpid()` should be error-checking and printing too.  So often, careful printing (e.g. `printf("cmd <<%s>>\n", str)` in the code in the question) reveals what is going on swiftly.  If you see the `>>` at the start of the line, the input has `'\r'` line endings, for example; if the `>>` is on a new line, the string contains a newline.